# Julia: pcaeig(X) yields "UndefVarError: fliplr not defined"

Tags: julia, pca, eigenvector

I am trying to get the eigenvector to do pca (principal component analysis). The package, DimensionalityReduction.jl offers a command that should do that very thing, pcaeig(X) where X is some matrix. My code is as follows

```
using DataFrames

using DimensionalityReduction

data = readtable("Midterm Data.csv")

T=size(data)[1]

n=size(data)[2]

erates = convert(Array,data[1:T,2:n])

eigvec = pcaeig(erates)
```

I do apologize that the formatting is bad, I don't quite remember how to put the code in a quote. Anyways, when I try to run this code, I get the following error: "UndefVarError: fliplr not defined". Now, to my knowledge, fliplr is a command used to flip a matrix (not a variable). It is also saying that the error is happening in the code for the package (not my code). Does this mean that I am out of luck and cannot use this package until it gets patched? If so, does anyone else know another method to get the eigenvector for pca?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the README of [DimensionalityReduction](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DimensionalityReduction.jl), the package is deprecated:

> The DimensionalityReduction package is deprecated. It is superseded by a new package [MultivariateStats](https://github.com/JuliaStats/MultivariateStats.jl).

The package does not work on recent versions of Julia and will not be updated to do so in the future. Use MultivariateStats instead.

Comment: Yeah I actually just noticed that. I'm looking at the pca analysis in MultivariateStats, and there doesn't seem to be a command that gives eigenvectors. Am I just not seeing it or did they do away with that functionality?

Comment: I am still having trouble figuring out how to get the eigenvectors using multivariatestats

Comment: Just grab them from the projection matrix https://github.com/JuliaStats/MultivariateStats.jl/blob/master/src/pca.jl#L7